# How to restart media player in kitkat [android]

Tags: java, android, media-player

What I am trying to do:

I was having a button that reuse the same instance of media player that will restart the `short sound effect` if the media player is still playing.

But when I tried using

```
if(mLockTickSound.isPlaying())
{
    mLockTickSound.pause();
    mLockTickSound.seekTo(0);
}

mLockTickSound.start();
```

This work under api 16

But in **KitKat** it will wait for the sound to be finished to enable to restart the sound again.

Is there any alternative for to `seekTo()`?

**edit:**

initialized it this way

```
mLockTickSound = MediaPlayer.create(LockerMain.this, R.raw.lock_tick);
```

audio is located in `raw`

Comment: I just tested this on my device running KitKat, and it works as expected.

Comment: @MikeM. have you tried clicking it multiple times?

Comment: Yep. I tried to break it; no go. It's working. I also checked different audio formats.

Comment: Oop, wait. How are you initializing your `MediaPlayer`?

Comment: @MikeM. updated bove, did you do it that way??

Comment: Yep, exactly how I did it. Are you testing on a device or an emulator?

Comment: Just FYI, I also got this to work using an `AssetFileDescriptor` and the `MediaPlayer.setDataSource()` method. So, if you're sure you don't have any other code interfering, I would think there's just something flaky with your device/emulator.

Comment: @MikeM. I think it would be the phone I am using which is sony xperia z1, thanks btw for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to simply restart your MediaPlayer whenever whatever you called happened. It is easy to do that, all you have to do is just `mp.reset();` then you do `mp.prepare();` then you finally do `mp.start();` You would have to do it in that order for it to work. Mind you, I have not yet tried it in KitKat, but theoretically it should work.